I am confused about the generalization of the convergence of random variable sequences on uncountable index sets.
It is difficult for me to find a unified definition that I feel must be correct. Let me give you an example, which is also the motivation for me to clarify this definition.
For a Brownian motion B,

$$\int_0^t 1_{\left\{B_u>0\right\}} d u=t \int_0^1 1_{\left\{B_{r v}>0\right\}} d v=t \int_0^1 1_{\left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} B_{t v}>0\right\}} d v \stackrel{\mathscr{L}}{\sim} t \int_0^1 1_{\left\{B_v>0\right\}} d v .$$
Just pay attention to the two items at both ends.

If we have (which can be derived from ILI):

$$\lim _{t \rightarrow+\infty} t \int_0^1 1_{\left\{B_u>0\right\}} d u=+\infty$$


***as the two r.v.'s $\int_0^t 1_{\left\{B_u>0\right\}} d u$ and $t
    \int_0^1 1_{\left\{B_u>0\right\}} d u$ have the same distribution
for every $t$, we have
$$ \lim _{t \rightarrow+\infty} \int_0^t 1_{\left\{B_u>0\right\}} d
u=+\infty \quad \text { in probability } $$***

***In order to prove the a.s. convergence, it suffices to observe that
the limit
$$ \lim _{t \rightarrow+\infty} \int_0^t 1_{\left\{B_u>0\right\}} d
u $$
exists a.s. as the integral is an increasing function of $t$. Hence
the proof is complete, because the a.s. limit and the limit in
probability necessarily coincide.***


My Question:

For the first one, I think it is the Slusky theorem that is used, treating positive infinity as a constant, then the convergence to positive infinity in distribution is equivalent to the convergence to positive infinity in the measure. I don't know if my understanding is correct, because when I regard this integral as a random variable, I am not dealing with a sequence, but a set of random variables with the positive semi-axis as the index. In this case, can we simply change n->+\infinity in the mathematical expression to t-> +\infinity when we say as convergence and convergence in probability?

The second problem comes from the first one. I can't write a mathematical expression that converges to positive infinity in probability, so I can't intuitively deduce that the as-convergence limit of the function 'sequence' $F_t$ where the limit exists is consistent with the limit that converges in probability.


